# JLabel text bigger than JLabel size and turning to "..."

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm really new to Java, and I wanted to make a simple GUI with a button which counts when you click it, I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5o3fMLPY7qY) tutorial on YouTube to get there. It went really nicely and everything worked. But one thing didn't, the end of the `JLabel` text goes from a number (`9`), to `...`.
Resizing the window manually brings the number back, so I tried resizing the font, window, button, and label sizes in the code when it launches, which *does* work, but I still get the same problem.

This is my code for the button:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
    button.addActionListener(this);
```

...which I believe would call this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    count++;
    label.setText("Number of clicks: " + count);
}
```

I've tried some other solutions on other questions but they haven't helped at all.

My full code for the GUI is this:

```
package javaGUI;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {
    private int count = 0;
    private JLabel label;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;

    public GUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();

        JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 75));

        label = new JLabel("Number of clicks: 0");
        label.setFont(new Font("System", Font.PLAIN, 22));

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(60, 100, 30, 100));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("GUI");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        count++;
        label.setText("Number of clicks: " + count);
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the frame is "packed" before it is made visible all the components are displayed at their preferred size.

The problem is that when you need to display multiple digits in the label, the labels preferred size increases but there is not enough space in the frame to display the label text completely so the text is truncated.

So the solution is to pack() the frame so the components in the GridLayout can once again be displayed at their preferred size:

```
label.setText("Number of clicks: " + count);
frame.pack();
```

Also note you should not set label properties in the ActionListener. The following properties should be set when you create the Label:

```
label = new JLabel("Number of clicks: 0");
label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to give the `JLabel` room to grow.

Here's one way to do it.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ClickMe implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ClickMe());
    }

    private int count = 0;
    private JLabel label;
    private JFrame frame;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Click Me");

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setFont(new Font("System", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 75));
        buttonPanel.add(button);

        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();

        label = new JLabel("Number of clicks: 0");
        label.setFont(new Font("System", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        labelPanel.add(label);

        frame.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        count++;
        label.setText("Number of clicks: " + count);
    }

}
```